# Can we deduce that $f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)(Re(f′(z₁))+iIm(f′(z₂)))$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

**Complex Mean Value Theorem**. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function defined on an open convex subset $D_{f}$ of $ℂ$ (or we can assume that $f$ is entire). Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct points in $D_{f}$. Then there exist $z_1,z_2∈(a,b)$ such that $$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{Re}f'(z_1)&=\operatorname{Re}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},\\
\operatorname{Im}f'(z_2)&=\operatorname{Im}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.\end{aligned}$$

My **questions** are:

(1) Can we deduce that: $f(b)=f(a)+(b-a)\bigl(\operatorname{Re}f'(z_1)+i\operatorname{Im}f'(z_2)\bigr)$?

(2) Let $b=s$ is any complex number different from $a$, can we deduce that the function $$    f(a)+(s-a)\bigl(\operatorname{Re}f'(z_1)+i\operatorname{Im} f'(z_2)\bigr)$$ is entire? Here $z_1$ and $z_2$ are given in function of $s$: $z₁=a+t₁(s-a)$ and $z₂=a+t₂(s-a)$ where $t₁,t₂∈(0,1)$

Comment: What does $(a,b)$ mean for complex $a,b$? their convex hull?

Comment: @oldrinb It would be the line segment between $a$ and $b$, not including the end points. The theorem comes from the real mean valute theorem, applied to the functions $t\mapsto \operatorname{Re}\bigl(f(a+t(b-a))/(b-a)\bigr)$ and $t\mapsto \operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(a+t(b-a))/(b-a)\bigr)$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: the last part I understood. Thank you for the first part though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation in question (1) can be rewritten as
$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\operatorname{Re}f'(z_1)+i\operatorname{Im}f'(z_2),$$
which is clearly true since $w=\operatorname{Re}w+i\operatorname{Im}w$ for *any* complex number $w$.

I am not sure I understand your question (2), since it seems to merely ask whether the function $f$, which is assumed to be entire, is entire.